# Recursively search for images, and move them to a date folder

Tags: terminal, bash

Asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792639/copy-all-images-on-system-to-one-folder) 9 months ago about how to copy images to a backup folder. That worked in that case! But now I have another problem. I have 233 GB of unsorted data, mostly images, and they are located in a unsorted directory structure.

I was thinking to sort the images based on date (if that is possible on all images), and keep the original filename.

I found a question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36634/move-huge-number-of-files-into-date-structured-directory-order), but I haven't tried it - afraid to mess things up.

My question is: how do I recursively search a folder, and move the image of type bmp, jpg, JPG, jpeg and gif to `/home/username/Documents/backup/[date]` folder (ex. `/home/username/Documents/backup/2013-06-10/DSC01158.JPG`), and if that folder dosen't exist - create it. And keep the filename, if possible.

System used: macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Edit:
The date has to be extracted from the metadata, because the files dosen´t include date in filename.

Comment: I assume the date is to be taken from the metadata of the file (aka the timestamp it has)? The example in the second link won't really help you then, there the date is taken from the filename.

Comment: Aha alright! But yes, that is correct. The timestamp is from the metadata, not the filename itself.

Comment: Ah, did only look at the accepted answer there. The others actually do more or less what you need as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to the folder you want to search and run

```
find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' | while read file; do
    ts=$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%Y-%m-%d' "$file")
    folder="/path/to/backup/folder/$ts"
    [[ -d "$folder" ]] || echo mkdir "$folder"
    echo mv "$file" "$folder/"
done
```

Best to test this on a small sample first, and remove both `echo`s if the output looks reasonable.

Comment: Would changing "mv" in the above command to "cp" allow you to copy as opposed to moving the files to a new directory? What does "$ts" mean?

Comment: @user26732 Yes, `cp` will copy the files instead of moving them, `ts` is the variable assigned in the line before (`ts=$(...)`). Run the part inside `( )` to see what it does.